# Volley set CSRF token in POST header request

Tags: android, django, android-volley

I am using django as backend for my android app. I have to make some post request for which i need CSRF token.
First I made a get request to backend to get CSRF token, then in next POST request I am using csrf obtained in previous request. I did this by overriding getHeaders method of JSON request.
I am still getting csrf verification failed at backend. Is this method wrong?
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: please share your code here

Answer (score 0):

Its a late answer. Anyway, I am adding one of the ways here if someone stumbles upon here looking for any answer :)

You can use csrf_exempt. It would exempt the view from CSRF consideration. I am not sure whether it is a major security risk or not, but it works.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def homePageView(request):
    data = request.POST.get('data')
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

More about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)!